# Error catching while instantiating a PHP object using a variable name

Tags: php, object

Using the following does not work as I had expected. With a valid className, it executes ok, but with a non-existing class, it just crashes without logging any error. Is this expected behaviour? If so, any suggestions for how to test if the object is properly instantiated?

```
$className = 'SomeClass';
try {
    $object = new $className;
    if (is_object($object)) {
        $logger->info(__METHOD__.' object created');
        return $object;
    } else {
        $logger->err(__METHOD__.' '.$className.' is not an object!');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $logger->err(__METHOD__.' error: '.print_r($e->getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: so neither info() nor err() is getting executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use the [class_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) function.

```
// Check that the class exists before trying to use it
if(class_exists($className)) {
    $object = new $className();
} else {
    // Do stuff for when class does not exist
}
```

Comment: How about `$object instanceof $className`?

Comment: For that to work `$object` would already have to be created, but as far as I understood the question, the script crashes upon trying to create `$object`.